# C# equivalent of Python's defaultdict (for lists) in C#

Tags: c#, python, defaultdict

What is the C# equivalent of doing:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(list)
>>> dct['key1'].append('value1')
>>> dct['key1'].append('value2')
>>> dct
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key1': ['value1', 'value2']})
```

For now, I have:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dct = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dct.Add("key1", "value1");
dct.Add("key1", "value2");
```

but that gives errors like "The best overloaded method match has invalid arguments".

Comment: the reason that gives an error is that you're not passing a `List<string>` for the dictionary value.

Comment: You're adding a `string` as the value when it should be a `List<string>`

Comment: `dct.Add("key1", new List<string>().Add("value1"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extension method you can add to your project to emulate the behavior you want:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary[key].Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, new List<TValue>{value});
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dct = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dct.AddOrUpdate("key1", "value1");
dct.AddOrUpdate("key1", "value2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be creating the record with specified key. Then you can add additional values to the value list:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dct = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dct.Add("key1", new List<string>{"value1"});
dct["key1"].Add("value2");
```

Comment: Any way to get the default values the Python version provides? This seems to require different code depending on whether or not a key is already present.

Comment: @user2357112, out of the box - no. You can always implement extension for that though

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dct = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string>() mList = new List<string>();
mList.Add("value1");
mList.Add("value2");

dct.Add("key1", mList);
```

Comment: Any way to get the default values the Python version provides? This seems to require different code depending on whether or not a key is already present.

Comment: No, You have to write code for it.